# React Native maps marker change destroys map state

Tags: react-native, marker, react-native-maps

I am using React Native maps, with real-time marker. This is my code.

```
const markers = useSelector(state => state.map.markers);

  const animate = useCallback(() => {
    if (map) {
      map.animateToRegion({
        latitude: location.latitude,
        longitude: location.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: location.latitudeDelta,
        longitudeDelta: location.longitudeDelta,
      });
    }
  }, [location, map]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location && isMapReady) {
      animate();
    }
  }, [animate, location, isMapReady]);

  const onMapLayout = () => {
    setIsMapReady(true);
  };
<MapView
      ref={mapView => {
        map = mapView;
      }}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}         
      region={location}
      onPress={() => {
        animate();
      }}
      onMapReady={onMapLayout}>
      {isMapReady &&
        markers.length !== 0 &&
        markers.map((marker, index) => (
          <MarkerAnimated
            key={index}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: marker.lat,
              longitude: marker.lon,
            }}                
          />
        ))}          
    </MapView>
```

So whenever the state changes the markers get updated and the marker is changed in real-time in the maps.

But with one issue: the real-time comes in like 10 seconds, within that time, if I try to drag maps to somewhere or zoom in or out of the maps, whenever the marker state changes all these changes will be lost, the zoom will be reset to the old one, and I'll move back to the initial location, etc.

How can I fix this? I want to continue scrolling inside the map, zoom in and out, meanwhile, the markers need to get updated on the app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very late but if you set the region to initialRegion in your map view it fixes this problem.

Comment: I fixed it long time ago...but unfortunately could not remember what I did right